# Batch encoding text files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this code to read a text file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type text.txt') do ( 
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!
)
pause
```

My question is that if i could advance every char in the file by 20 places like "a" would be "t". it can have numbers and symbols too. the txt file is 400 line long and there is between 1 and 120 char per line. does any one know how i could do this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get, what you say. Do you want to replace every "a" by "t"?

Comment: yes and every b with u and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this will not handle all the posibilities, but

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :setTables

    set "inputFile=inputFile.txt"


    for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%a in ("%inputFile%") do (
        set "data=%%a"
        call :handleProblems
        set "out="
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ('cmd /v:off /q /u /c "echo(!data!"^|more') do (
            if defined "%%b" ( 
                set "out=!out!!"%%b"!"
            ) else (
                set "out=!out!%%b"
            )
        )
        echo(!out!
        endlocal
    )

    exit /b

:handleProblems
    set "data=%data:!=~%"
    set "data=%data:<=^<%"
    set "data=%data:>=^>%"
    set "data=%data:&=^&%"
    set "data=%data:|=^|%"
    set "data=%data:)=^)%"
    exit /b

:setTables
    set ""a"=t"
    set ""b"=u"
    set ""c"=v"
    set ""d"=w"
    set ""e"=x"
    set ""f"=y"
    set ""g"=z"
    set ""h"=a"
    set ""i"=b"
    set ""j"=c"
    set ""k"=d"
    set ""l"=e"
    set ""m"=f"
    set ""n"=g"
    set ""o"=h"
    set ""p"=i"
    set ""q"=j"
    set ""r"=k"
    set ""s"=l"
    set ""t"=m"
    set ""u"=n"
    set ""v"=o"
    set ""w"=p"
    set ""x"=q"
    set ""y"=r"
    set ""z"=s"
    set ""~"=!"
    set ""^&"=&"

    exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GnuSed and the `"y/abc/tuv/"` transliteration command which would replace a with t, b with u and c with v

This syntax works - just extend the character sets:

```
sed "y/abc/tuv/" "file.txt" >"newfile.txt"
```

Comment: Do i need any extra software.